# how can css let image bigger than screen?

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="/path/to/a/image/maybe/bigger/than/screen"/>
</div>
```

And there is the LESS:

```
.image-container{
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  img{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

The image is mostly `width: 1600px`, but height is unknwon.

The screen-width is mostly smaller than 1600px.

I want the image can show it's center part even in small screens. The image's height is unknown.
 **And the container's height should equals image's, as a block let the afters not overlap on.**

Current LESS cannot work as expect.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. Is there something that is not working? Can you elaborate on what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You will need to add `height` for the parent
- Position the `image` by adding `position:absolute`

```css
.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/1600/200" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Is it possible to left the `height` of parent is also auto?

Answer (score 1):

Set the image as a background with center positioning. Maybe something like:

```
body { background:url('PATH/TO/IMAGE') no-repeat center top; }
```

Comment: Thank you, but i cannot use this as a block element if using background

Answer (score 1):

Sheldon is correct about setting the image as a background on your css, but if you want the image to be centered on the screen you'll need more css.  Basically something like this:

```
.img { 
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(path to image);
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-size:cover;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

You can also adjust your height according to how you want it

Comment: `background-size`! Thank you, but the container's height is also unknown make the height `0`